# How to implement onChange with Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have following component created with Formik:

```js
type Props = FieldHookConfig<string> & {
  placeholder?: string;
  onChange?: (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => void
};

const Text= ({ ...props }: Props) => {
  const [field] = useField(props);

  return <Input {...field} placeholder={props.placeholder} />;
};
export default Text;
```

Here, I am using this component:

```js
        <Formik initialValues={{}} onSubmit={() => { }}>
            {() => (
                <Form>
                    <Text
                        name="firstName"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="FirsName"
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />
                </form>
            )}
        </Formik>
```

How to implement onChange in Text component which comes from `field` state